# Git branch detached automatically on EC2

Tags: git, github, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04

I have couple of production systems running on ubuntu EC2 instances. Last night I was deploying some patch to the production but github error ed out saying "branch detached".

I am wondering how did it happen. Whats the reason for that? 
Also, how do I avoid such things in the future?

Comment: Can you give us a little more information about how you deploy your patches? Are patches just a series of new Git commits you're pulling onto repos on the EC2 instances? It would be good if you could paste the specific error message you're getting, too.

Comment: while deploying new patch did u pull with branch name or did u do checkout?